ASP.NET Core Docker Container Not Accessible via Exposed Port on Host Machine
I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core MVC web application inside a Docker container. The container seems to start correctly, and the logs show that the application is listening on the expected port http://[::]:8080. However, when I try to access the application from my host machine using http://localhost:8081, I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in the browser.
This is the Dockerfile:
# Use the official .NET Core runtime as the base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

# Use the .NET Core SDK for building the project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerWebMVC.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DockerWebMVC.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DockerWebMVC.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Publish the project to get the deployment-ready binaries
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerWebMVC.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

# Final stage: Create a runtime container image
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerWebMVC.dll"]

Here's what I've done so far:

Built the Docker image using a Dockerfile that defines the ASP.NET Core project.
Ran the container with the following command: docker run -d -p 8081:80 dockerwebmvc .
Checked the logs inside the container, which indicate that the application is running on http://[::]:8080.
Executed curl http://localhost:8080 inside the container, and it correctly returns the HTML of the application’s homepage.

However, when I attempt to access the application from my host machine via http://localhost:8081, it doesn't work.
Additional details:

The Docker network is using the default bridge mode.
I checked for potential firewall or port issues, but everything seems to be configured correctly.
The application runs fine locally outside of Docker.

Could someone help me identify why I can't access the application from my host machine despite the container running correctly? Any advice on debugging steps or potential issues with the Docker configuration would be appreciated.


Specifically, I used the docker run -d -p 8081:80 dockerwebmvc command to start the container and expected to be able to access the application via http://localhost:8081 on my host machine.

And

The logs within the container indicate that the application is running and listening on http://[::]:8080

Application is running on 8080 port inside the container but you are mapping the 80 one, you need to map the 8080 instead:
docker run -d -p 8081:8080 .....

Since .NET 8 applications are using 8080 port by default - see the Default ASP.NET Core port changed from 80 to 8080:
And EXPOSE is used just for documentation purposes and does not actually do something:

The EXPOSE instruction doesn't actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.


Your answer is very useful for me. I've lots of time wasting on that problem & your answer solve that in a seconds. Thanks a Lot!.

@ParthTirgar was glad to help! If answer works for you please feel free to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left ;)
